# Partitioning PyArrow Parquet file and writing it out sorted to a dataset

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

I have a PyArrow Parquet file that is too large to process in memory. Because data can be easily partitioned into different shards, I'd like to manually partition this and create a PyArrow dataset out of the file. While I am partitioning, the rows within the partition themselves need to be re-sorted, so that iterating the data can be done in a natural order.

Here is a schema snippet if it is relevant. The partitioning key is `chain_id`:

```py
pa.schema([
    ("chain_id", pa.uint32()),
    ("pair_id", pa.uint64()),
    ("block_number", pa.uint32()),
    ("timestamp", pa.timestamp("s")),
    ("tx_hash", pa.binary(32)),
    ("log_index", pa.uint32()),
])
```

The process I was planning to use it

- Determine partition ids beforehand (`chain_id` in the above schema)
- Open a new dataset for writing
- For each partition id

  - Create an in-memory temporary PyArrow table
  - Read (iterate batches) the source Parquet file

    - Identify rows belonging to this partition and add them to the in-memory table
  - Sort the rows in memory
  - Append table to the dataset

However the documentation on [FileSystemDataset](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.FileSystemDataset.html) on PyArrow is skinny. My question along the lines are

- How do I add full tables to a `FilesystemDataset`, assuming the table is the whole content of a partition itself?
- Is there any existing tools to partition (PyArrow) Parquet files to datasets, without needing a write a manual script?
- What kind of ordering guarantees `pyarrow.dataset.FileSystemDataset` gives assuming I want to always read the data in the insertd presorted order with `to_batches`?
- Any other PyArrwo tips dealing with data and datasets that does not fit into RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the [dataset](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/dataset.html) api. It can [filter](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.filter) on `chain_id` without loading, and [write the partitions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset). Dataset reading does maintain order.

My own [partitioning utility](https://github.com/coady/graphique/blob/main/graphique/shell.py) is similar to what you need. It provides sorting, and could be further adapted or provide ideas.

Comment: Thank you sir, the partitioning utility is a good example to look upon. I will need to modify it a bit, but is an excellent starting point.